# Is it possible to open a context menu from a map overlay item in android?

Tags: android, dictionary, overlay, android-contextmenu

This below code works fine opening an alert dialog. I was wondering if it's possible to open a context menu from within a map overlay class?

```
@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
      AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
      dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
      dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
      dialog.show();

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No you can't open a context menu on mapView

I wanted to have onTap event open context menu I tried most of methods but all in vain.

Maybe you should use Alert.Builder with it's three button to perform actions if you want. or better have a customized alert view.

```
registerForContextMenu(mapView);

openContextMenu(mapView);
```

that don't works

Comment: After realizing context menus are not (easily) possible from mapViews, I just placed my ImageViews right in the Fragment (`<fragment ... android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" ...><ImageView android:id="@+id/myimg".../></fragment>`) and where able to access them in onCreate of FragmentActivity via `mapFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.myimg);`

Answer (score 0):

This may work.

```
registerForContextMenu(mapView); // in onCreate

protected boolean onTap(int index) {
    mTappedItem = index;
    openContextMenu();
    return true;
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // do something if mTappedItem is valid.
    return true;
}
```